# Tomcat ever growing open files/connections

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, gwt

I'm running a GWT site in Tomcat 6 on a CentOS 6.2 server. 
I've run into the "Too many open files" error. As we have many devices in the field which send small messages every 10 seconds over the internet to our tomcat server, I suspected connections not being closed properly. However, I could not find any reference to that, only suggestions on the net to enlarge the amount of allowed open files. 
So I "fixed" it with adding the following lines in /etc/init.d/tomcat6 :

ulimit -Hn 16384

ulimit -Sn 16384

As I see it, this should not be the way dealing with this, but I've read somewhere that the file usage of tomcat keeps on growing, by design, until it reaches tomcat's limit (2000 IIRC) and when that limit has been reached, tomcat cleans it up.

So I assumed the problem to be solved (also because I couldn't find any other solution), until tomcat stopped working properly, without any indication in logs except from corrupted/unfinished handling of http posts. So I searched further in the hope of finding the core problem. I found someone has solved it by switching from OpenJDK 1.6 to Oracle's own JDK 1.6. But I'm using Oracle's JDK 1.7.0_40, so this can't be the issue either.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Eyso

Comment: You you attempted using lsof to determine what files are open?

Comment: Yes, I the command lsof | grep tomcat | grep -v grep | wc -l

Comment: At the time the server was having trouble, the output was about 7992 ( I made it log every minute)

Comment: It doesn't get more than 8000 btw.

Comment: And what files are open? How many concurrent connections do you allow? Do you allow keep alive?

Comment: Considering what files are open by tomcat, mostly TCP connections. I can't find anything specific about the amount of concurrent connections nor about the keep alive (I haven't set up this system, therefore I had to search for it) so I think that's all Tomcat's default values. The only thing I can find is the session timeout in WEB-INF/web.xml, which is 120 seconds.